# Waht exactly does it mean for 2 3D vectors to be orthogonal (in 3D) w.r.t dot product = 0

Tags: orthogonality

I am suddenly puzzled by ho to know (when in 3D) with respect to which axis is the vector being rotated when the dot product between then is =0. for example: if i rotate 90degrees (pi/2 radians) along Z axis the vector [1 1 1] i get : [-1 1 1] which is at about 70° from [1 1 1] according to the formula $\cos \theta = \frac{x^\top y}{||x||\cdot||y||}$ I think i cannot visualize (anymore) what is happening when it comes to 3D ans its very frustrating... For me if i rotate along Z by 90 degrees the vectors should be at 90 degrees...? but again i must be missing something basic i guess?

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring different angles.  The 70 degrees you are getting is the angle between the two vectors.  The  90 degrees is the angle between the **projections** of those vectors in the xy-plane.

Comment: thanks. And which rotation (along which axis ) and which angle would you do to get an 90 ° angle between the 2 vectors ?